# how to find the location of a command like rar in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, rar

I installed rar, but I want to know where it is stored?

I did:

sudo apt-get rar

it installed it, but typing : sudo unrar file.rar doesn't work, says it doesn't know what the command is.

Comment: as you can see from myanswer below the syntax for using rar is "rar x filename". You cannot use unrar without installing it first. The syntax for unrar would be "unrar e filename"

Comment: And as an aside, *if* the command would have worked, then typing `which unrar` would have told you which program would be executed. (And are you sure you would need `sudo` to run the command? Don't use `sudo` for everything you do!)

Comment: @arjan: +1 for the 'sudo' advice

Answer (score 8):

```
$which rar
```

Will tell you where rar is located.

Comment: ...but not if running `rar` does not work, right? (Well, `unrar`, for this question.)

Comment: I see that tapan already answered - unrar is a different program

Answer (score 5):

unrar is a different program from rar. You'll have to install that too. Mostly all your programs will be stored in /usr/bin or /usr/sbin . You can add this function to your .bashrc file and then just use the command extract to extract any archive :

```
extract () {
     if [ -f $1 ] ; then
         case $1 in
             *.tar.bz2)   tar xjf $1        ;;
             *.tar.gz)    tar xzf $1     ;;
             *.bz2)       bunzip2 $1       ;;
             *.rar)       rar x $1     ;;
             *.gz)        gunzip $1     ;;
             *.tar)       tar xf $1        ;;
             *.tbz2)      tar xjf $1      ;;
             *.tgz)       tar xzf $1       ;;
             *.zip)       unzip $1     ;;
             *.Z)         uncompress $1  ;;
             *.7z)        7z x $1    ;;
             *)           echo "'$1' cannot be extracted via extract()" ;;
         esac
     else
         echo "'$1' is not a valid file"
     fi
}
```